# Como faço para rodar a animação toda vez que clico no mesmo botão?

Tags: javascript

```html
<html>
<body>
<style>



#novo{
border:1px solid red;
width:375px;
height:467px;
background-image: url("file:///storage/emulated/0/download/inicialAnim.png");
animation: Anima 0.5s  steps(5) infinite;
transform:scale(0.6);
}
@keyframes Anima{
from{background-position:0px;}to{
background-position:-1875px;}

}
#btn1{
width:50px;
height:50px;
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:100px;
position:absolute;
left:563px;
bottom:50px;
background-color:#FF0900;
}

</style>
<div id = "novo"></div>
<div id = "btn1"></div>
<script>




var verify;
var anima = document.getElementById("novo");
var anim = document.getElementById("btn1");



anim.onclick = function play(){

anima.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
verify = true;
if(verify == true){
anim.addEventListener("click",verifica);

}

}

function verifica(){

anima.style.animationPlayState = "running";
anim.addEventListener("click",play);

}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo Danilo, tente ser mais claro no que você deseja fazer.

Comment: Ok.vou ser mais especifico

Comment: Obrigado André. Gostei do site quando eu tiver com dúvidas vou tentar tirar aqui valeu cara,valeu mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar uma só função para isso, alternando o valor da variável `verify` em `true` e `false`, usando um `if..else`. No seu código, a função `play` é anônima e não vai ser chamada no `.addEventListener`. Veja:

```js
var verify;
var anima = document.getElementById("novo");
var anim = document.getElementById("btn1");

verifica();
function verifica(){
   if(!verify){
      verify = true;
      anima.style.animationPlayState = "running";
   }else{
      verify = false;
      anima.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
   }
   anim.addEventListener("click", verifica);
}
```

```css
#novo{
border:1px solid red;
width:375px;
height:467px;
background-image: url("https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg");
animation: Anima 0.5s  steps(5) infinite;
transform:scale(0.6);
}
@keyframes Anima{
from{background-position:0px;}to{
background-position:-1875px;}

}
#btn1{
width:50px;
height:50px;
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:100px;
position:absolute;
left:563px;
bottom:50px;
background-color:#FF0900;
}
```

```html
<div id = "novo"></div>
<div id = "btn1">play/pause</div>
```